# Express: router cannot read POST request

Tags: node.js

In my server.js:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api/member.js'));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));


app.listen(3000 ,() => console.log('server running on port 3000'));
```

My member.js:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('POST');

});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('GET');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When i send a POST request from my homepage, only router.get get called. If I comment out the router.get, it says 'Cannot GET /api'. How to fix?

Comment: Please add the code you used to send the POST request.If it hits the GET route then you're most probably not making POST request. Also if you test this in Chrome you can see in the DevTools in Network tab what request was sent.

Comment: I forgot to change the method on the form to POST! Thank you.